# Retrieve position of elements with setting some criteria in numpy

Tags: python, numpy

For the given 2d array of data, how to retrieve the position (index) of 7 and 11 in the bold.
Because only they are the elements surrounded by same value in the neighbours

```
  import numpy as np
    data  = np.array([
        [0,1,2,3,4,7,6,7,8,9,10], 
        [3,3,3,4,7,7,7,8,11,12,11],  
        [3,3,3,5,7,**7**,7,9,11,11,11],
        [3,4,3,6,7,7,7,10,11,**11**,11],
        [4,5,6,7,7,9,10,11,11,11,11]
        ])

    print data
```

Comment: Isn't the seven above the seven you starred also one surrounded by the same value?

Comment: not in my definition, because 4 and 6 are neighbours of 7 in the first line

Comment: Whoops, misread that somehow!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using scipy, you could characterize such points as those which are both the maximum and the minimum of its neighborhood:

```
import numpy as np
import scipy.ndimage.filters as filters

def using_filters(data):
    return np.where(np.logical_and.reduce(
        [data == f(data, footprint=np.ones((3,3)), mode='constant', cval=np.inf)
         for f in (filters.maximum_filter, filters.minimum_filter)]))  

using_filters(data)
# (array([2, 3]), array([5, 9]))
```

Using only numpy, you could compare `data` with 8 shifted slices of itself to find the points which are equal:

```
def using_eight_shifts(data):
    h, w = data.shape
    data2 = np.empty((h+2, w+2))
    data2[(0,-1),:] = np.nan
    data2[:,(0,-1)] = np.nan
    data2[1:1+h,1:1+w] = data

    result = np.where(np.logical_and.reduce([
        (data2[i:i+h,j:j+w] == data)
        for i in range(3)
        for j in range(3)
        if not (i==1 and j==1)]))
    return result
```

As you can see above, this strategy makes an expanded array which has a border of NaNs around the data. This allows the shifted slices to be expressed as `data2[i:i+h,j:j+w]`.

If you know that you are going to be comparing against neighbors, it might behoove you to define `data` with a border of NaNs from the very beginning so you don't have to make a second array as done above.

Using eight shifts (and comparisons) is much faster than looping over each cell in `data` and comparing it against its neighbors:

```
def using_quadratic_loop(data):
    return np.array([[i,j]
            for i in range(1,np.shape(data)[0]-1)
            for j in range(1,np.shape(data)[1]-1)
            if np.all(data[i-1:i+2,j-1:j+2]==data[i,j])]).T
```

Here is a benchmark:

```
using_filters            : 0.130
using_eight_shifts       : 0.340
using_quadratic_loop     : 18.794
```

---

Here is the code used to produce the benchmark:

```
import timeit
import operator
import numpy as np
import scipy.ndimage.filters as filters
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

data  = np.array([
    [0,1,2,3,4,7,6,7,8,9,10], 
    [3,3,3,4,7,7,7,8,11,12,11],  
    [3,3,3,5,7,7,7,9,11,11,11],
    [3,4,3,6,7,7,7,10,11,11,11],
    [4,5,6,7,7,9,10,11,11,11,11]
    ])

data = np.tile(data, (50,50))

def using_filters(data):
    return np.where(np.logical_and.reduce(
        [data == f(data, footprint=np.ones((3,3)), mode='constant', cval=np.inf)
         for f in (filters.maximum_filter, filters.minimum_filter)]))    


def using_eight_shifts(data):
    h, w = data.shape
    data2 = np.empty((h+2, w+2))
    data2[(0,-1),:] = np.nan
    data2[:,(0,-1)] = np.nan
    data2[1:1+h,1:1+w] = data

    result = np.where(np.logical_and.reduce([
        (data2[i:i+h,j:j+w] == data)
        for i in range(3)
        for j in range(3)
        if not (i==1 and j==1)]))
    return result


def using_quadratic_loop(data):
    return np.array([[i,j]
            for i in range(1,np.shape(data)[0]-1)
            for j in range(1,np.shape(data)[1]-1)
            if np.all(data[i-1:i+2,j-1:j+2]==data[i,j])]).T

np.testing.assert_equal(using_quadratic_loop(data), using_filters(data))
np.testing.assert_equal(using_eight_shifts(data), using_filters(data))

timing = dict()
for f in ('using_filters', 'using_eight_shifts', 'using_quadratic_loop'):
    timing[f] = timeit.timeit('{f}(data)'.format(f=f),
                              'from __main__ import data, {f}'.format(f=f),
                              number=10) 

for f, t in sorted(timing.items(), key=operator.itemgetter(1)):
    print('{f:25}: {t:.3f}'.format(f=f, t=t))
```

Comment: Thanks for your nice explaination. Considering the speed, your def using_filters(data) method is good. I have one question if I want to get the location of a specific value, say 7 instead of any values, how can I change your code?

Comment: Let `x, y = using_filters(data)`. `mask = (data[x,y] == 7)`. Then the locations where `data` equals 7 would be given by `x[mask]` and `y[mask]`.

Answer (score 3):

I used a list comprehension but there may be a better way

```
A = [(i,j) for i in range(1,data.shape[0]-1) for j in range(1,data.shape[1]-1) if all((data[i-1:i+2,j-1:j+2]==data[i,j]).flatten())]
```

EDIT:

If you want the form array([i,j],dtype=int64) then you just need to modify the first part:

```
A= [np.array([i,j], dtype=np.int64) for i in range(1,data.shape[0]-1) for j in range(1,data.shape[1]-1) if all((data[i-1:i+2,j-1:j+2]==data[i,j]).flatten())]
```

Answer (score 1):

I have tested it and the following code works:

```
for i in range(1,np.shape(data)[0]-1):
    for j in range(1,np.shape(data)[1]-1):
        if np.all(data[i-1:i+2,j-1:j+2]==data[i,j]):
            print np.array([i,j], dtype=np.int64)
```

Comment: looks straight, but i want to get answers in this form:(array([2, 3], dtype=int64), array([5, 9], dtype=int64))

Answer (score 1):

```
displacements = [[-1, -1], [-1, 0], [-1, 1], [0, -1], [0, 1], [1, -1], [1, 0], [1, 1]]

for x in range(1, data.shape[0] - 1):
    for y in range(1, data.shape[1] - 1):
        if all((data[x][y] == data[x + a][y + b]) for a, b in displacements):
            print np.array([x, y], dtype=np.int64)
```

Not as succint as the other answers, but it's clear and prints the correct output. I think it's also a little easier to change/add displacement values.

Whoops, didn't realize you wanted all 8 neighbors. Easy fix though. :)