# Retrieve position of specified element sourrounded by same element

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

For the given 2d array of data, how to retrieve the position (index) of 7 which is itself surrounded by same value in the neighbors.

```
import numpy as np
import scipy.ndimage.filters as filters
    data  = np.array([[0,1,2,3,4,7,6,7,8,9,10], 
        [3,3,3,4,7,7,7,8,11,12,11],  
        [3,3,3,5,7,7,7,9,11,11,11],
        [3,4,3,6,7,7,7,10,11,11,11],
        [4,5,6,7,7,9,10,11,11,11,11]])
```

I want only the position [2, 5]. The 7 is exclusively surrounded by other 7s.
The following code gives answer for any values in the code.

```
 answer = np.where(np.logical_and.reduce([data == f(data, footprint=np.ones((3,3)), mode='constant', cval=np.inf) for f in (filters.maximum_filter, filters.minimum_filter)]))
    print answer
```

I want to force it applicable to specified value (7) only.
The above code is from the answer at [Retrieve position of elements with setting some criteria in numpy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23025497/retrieve-position-of-elements-with-setting-some-criteria-in-numpy)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another `logical_and`, check for specified value, and voila.

```
specified_value = 7

answer = np.where(np.logical_and(
                      np.logical_and.reduce(
                          [data == f(data, 
                                     footprint=np.ones((3,3)), 
                                     mode='constant', 
                                     cval=np.inf) for f in 
                                         (filters.maximum_filter, 
                                          filters.minimum_filter)]),
                      data == specified_value))
```