# set the elements not included by np.where as np.nan

Tags: python, numpy

How can I set all the elements that are not 7 as np.nan?

```
import numpy as np
data  = np.array([[0,1,2,3,4,7,6,7,8,9,10], 
        [3,3,3,4,7,7,7,8,11,12,11],  
        [3,3,3,5,7,7,7,9,11,11,11],
        [3,4,3,6,7,7,7,10,11,11,11],
        [4,5,6,7,7,9,10,11,11,11,11]])

result = np.where(data==7) 
data[~result] = np.nan
print data

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "M:\test.py", line 10, in <module>
    data[~result] = np.nan
TypeError: bad operand type for unary ~: 'tuple'
```

Comment: `data[data!=7] = np.nan`

Comment: But in my program, I have to use np.where

Comment: So, want to change the values of those indices not included in result as np.nan

Comment: Can you do `result = np.where(data!=7)` then `data[result] = np.nan`?

Comment: Sorry but in my program np.where(data==7) must be done.

Comment: I want the method after that

Comment: @neha Why must you use `np.where`?

Comment: @Ophion in case of my real world problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There must be a better way but this is the best I can think of right now.  Make another array of all `np.nan`, and then replace the values at the indices in `result` with the real values:

```
data_nan = np.full(data.shape, np.nan)
data_nan[result] = data[result]
data = data_nan
```

If you want to get a list of all indices that are not in `result`, you could do this, though I think the above is probably better:

```
inc = np.core.rec.fromarrays(result)
all_ind = np.core.rec.fromarrays(np.indices(data.shape).reshape(2,-1))
exc = np.setdiff1d(all_ind, inc)
data[exc['f0'], exc['f1']] = np.nan
```

This works by turning each pair of indices into one element of a structured array, so that they can be compared as set elements to a similar array of all indices.  Then we do the set difference of these and get the rest.

Comment: why the values are -2147483648 than np.nan

Comment: Oh, sorry, that's actually because an int array cannot have `nan`. Try just `data[0, 0] = np.nan` and you'll see that it gives some large negative integer.  You must first convert `data` to a float array if you want to use `np.nan`.  My edit does this.

Comment: i prefered your first method than second one

Answer (score 3):

Use the 3-argument form of [np.where](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html):

```
In [49]: np.where(data==7, data, np.nan)
Out[49]: 
array([[ nan,  nan,  nan,  nan,  nan,   7.,  nan,   7.,  nan,  nan,  nan],
       [ nan,  nan,  nan,  nan,   7.,   7.,   7.,  nan,  nan,  nan,  nan],
       [ nan,  nan,  nan,  nan,   7.,   7.,   7.,  nan,  nan,  nan,  nan],
       [ nan,  nan,  nan,  nan,   7.,   7.,   7.,  nan,  nan,  nan,  nan],
       [ nan,  nan,  nan,   7.,   7.,  nan,  nan,  nan,  nan,  nan,  nan]])
```

or

```
In [62]: np.choose(data==7, [np.nan, data])
Out[62]: 
array([[ nan,  nan,  nan,  nan,  nan,   7.,  nan,   7.,  nan,  nan,  nan],
       [ nan,  nan,  nan,  nan,   7.,   7.,   7.,  nan,  nan,  nan,  nan],
       [ nan,  nan,  nan,  nan,   7.,   7.,   7.,  nan,  nan,  nan,  nan],
       [ nan,  nan,  nan,  nan,   7.,   7.,   7.,  nan,  nan,  nan,  nan],
       [ nan,  nan,  nan,   7.,   7.,  nan,  nan,  nan,  nan,  nan,  nan]])
```

---

Regarding the requirement that the integer indices returned by [using_filters](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23025647/190597) be used in this solution, I think there is a better alternative. If you were to remove the `np.where` from `using_filters`:

```
def using_filters(data):
    return np.logical_and.reduce(
        [data == f(data, footprint=np.ones((3,3)), mode='constant', cval=np.inf)
         for f in (filters.maximum_filter, filters.minimum_filter)])
```

then `using_filters` would return a boolean mask. [Using a boolean mask](https://web.archive.org/web/20150802020005/http://wiki.scipy.org/Tentative_NumPy_Tutorial#head-d55e594d46b4f347c20efe1b4c65c92779f06268) would make this problem even easier:

```
import numpy as np
import scipy.ndimage.filters as filters

def using_filters(data):
    return np.logical_and.reduce(
        [data == f(data, footprint=np.ones((3,3)), mode='constant', cval=np.inf)
         for f in (filters.maximum_filter, filters.minimum_filter)])


data  = np.array([[0,1,2,3,4,7,6,7,8,9,10], 
        [3,3,3,4,7,7,7,8,11,12,11],  
        [3,3,3,5,7,7,7,9,11,11,11],
        [3,4,3,6,7,7,7,10,11,11,11],
        [4,5,6,7,7,9,10,11,11,11,11]], dtype='float')

result = using_filters(data)
data[~result] = np.nan
print data
# [[ nan  nan  nan  nan  nan  nan  nan  nan  nan  nan  nan]
#  [ nan  nan  nan  nan  nan  nan  nan  nan  nan  nan  nan]
#  [ nan  nan  nan  nan  nan   7.  nan  nan  nan  nan  nan]
#  [ nan  nan  nan  nan  nan  nan  nan  nan  nan  11.  nan]
#  [ nan  nan  nan  nan  nan  nan  nan  nan  nan  nan  nan]]
```

Comment: I want the method after that.

Comment: I am just looking for an alternative to the answer of askewchan in the same way he has done

Comment: askewchan's answer works well and is in fact faster than using np.where in this case. Why not accept his solution?

Comment: is not there direct way to do it with out creating new array?

Comment: Yes. My answer creates the array directly. It doesn't matter that you need to call `np.where(data==7)`. That doesn't preclude you calling `np.where(data==7, data, np.nan)`, or `np.choose(data==7, [np.nan, data])` too.

Comment: no, no i want to apply after np.where. my real problem is here:         http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23025497/retrieve-position-of-elements-with-setting-some-criteria-in-numpy

Comment: because the result that i need (index positions) are retrieved by np.where function i have to apply that index

Comment: It seems you could negate the argument to `np.where` in that solution, but maybe not? I don't fully understand the method.

Answer (score 2):

You can get the values you want from `data`, and fill `data` with `nan` and then copy the values back to `data`:

```
import numpy as np
data  = np.array([[0,1,2,3,4,7,6,7,8,9,10], 
        [3,3,3,4,7,7,7,8,11,12,11],  
        [3,3,3,5,7,7,7,9,11,11,11],
        [3,4,3,6,7,7,7,10,11,11,11],
        [4,5,6,7,7,9,10,11,11,11,11]], float)

result = np.where(data==7) 

values = data[result]
data.fill(np.nan)
data[result] = values
```