# Numpy NaN returning as 'nan'

Tags: python-2.7, pandas, numpy

This is a part of my code:

```
df['ColZ'] = np.where(
            (df['ColA'] == 'AA') & (df['ColB'] == 'BB'),
            'GOOD!',
            np.where((df['ColA'] == 'BB') & (df['ColB'] == 'AA'),
            'BAD...',
            np.nan))
```

But the 'nan's are populated as 'nan' (string) instead of NaN.

Naturally, df.isnull().any() returns False, because the 'nan's are registered as strings.

Where did I go wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try replace `nan` to `NaN`:

```
df = df.replace('nan', np.nan)
```

Comment: Haha @jezrael, I'll use your suggestion for now. Is my syntax correct?

Comment: or problem is `numpy.where` convert `np.nan` to string `nan` ?

Comment: Looking at [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23233542/set-the-elements-not-included-by-np-where-as-np-nan) it seems you are right. This behavior is extremely odd..