# Python2.7: Not able to create null vales with np.where and np.nan methods

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas, numpy

I'm having difficulty resolving an issue whereby after using np.where to compare 2 row values within a column (position), with the result being assigned to a new column (null value is created if condition is false), i am unable to use fillna method to replace the null values with the values of the newly created columns

Upon using df.isnull().sum() to check for null values, the results show that there are no null values for the newly created columns (even though i have used np.nan)

In summary, I want to merge the values within the 3 columns: clear lap, overtaken, overtook.

```
df['clear lap?'] = np.where((df['position'] == df['position'].shift()), str("clear"), np.nan)
df['overtaken'] = np.where((df['position'] > df['position'].shift()), str("got overtaken"), np.nan)
df['overtook'] = np.where((df['position'] < df['position'].shift()), str("overtook"), np.nan)

df['clear lap?'].fillna(df['overtaken'], inplace=True)
df['clear lap?'].fillna(df['overtook'], inplace=True)
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Could you add some data?

Comment: @Cleb Hey i have added the data

Comment: Could you not post images please.

Comment: The image does not help. Ideally, you would provide a dataframe one can easily copy and paste along with your desired output.

Answer (score 1):

Let's try an experiment.

```
>>> v = np.random.choice(2, 10) 
>>> v
array([0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0])
```

```
>>> np.where(v, 'overtook', np.nan)
array(['nan', 'nan', 'overtook', 'overtook', 'nan', 'nan', 'nan',
       'overtook', 'overtook', 'nan'],
      dtype='<U32')
```

Because `np.where` by default returns an array with homogenous `dtype`s, you have `np.nan` values coerced to strings, so you get `'nan'` instead of `NaN`.

One workaround would be to perform substitution with a `pd.Series` object, like this -

```
>>> s = pd.Series(v)
>>> m = s.gt(0)
>>> s[m] = 'overtook'
>>> s[~m] = np.nan
s
0         NaN
1         NaN
2    overtook
3    overtook
4         NaN
5         NaN
6         NaN
7    overtook
8    overtook
9         NaN
dtype: object
```

Answer (score 0):

COLDSPEED already explained what might happen. I found some other similar problems [Numpy NaN returning as 'nan'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42921652/numpy-nan-returning-as-nan)

As suggested by jezrael in the question above, try to use

```
df = df.replace('nan', np.nan)
```

to fix this if you still want to use `np.where`

Also, think you could use

```
df.isin(["nan", np.nan])
```

or

```
df['clear lap?'].isin(["nan", np.nan])
```

to check whether there are `"nan"` created by accident in a series or your data frame.